# Getting NameError: name 'countVectorizer' is not defined in Pycharm

Tags: python, countvectorizer

Need help with the error
NameError: name 'countVectorizer' is not defined in PyCharm

I am trying to execute the FEATURE EXTRACTION code from this source
https://github.com/chdoig/pytexas2015-ml

File Name: 1-Feature_extraction.ipynb

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


train_data = pd.read_csv('labeledTrainData.tsv',sep='\t')
print(train_data)
print(train_data.iloc[1].review)

test_data = pd.read_csv('testData.tsv',sep = '\t')
print(test_data)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

train_data['review_len'] = train_data.review.apply(len)
len_pl = plt.hist(train_data.review_len.values)
plt.show(len_pl)

#describe negative reviews
print(train_data[train_data.sentiment==0].describe())
print(train_data[train_data.sentiment==1].describe())

#inspecting outliers
print(train_data[train_data.review_len==52].review.all())
print(train_data[train_data.review_len==13708].review.all())

#word exrtaction

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vocab = ['awesome', 'terrible']
simple_vectorizer = countVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab)
bow = simple_vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data.review).todense()
print(bow)
```

**Error/Warning:**
C:\Users\hi\PycharmProjects\Practice2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/hi/PycharmProjects/Practice2/P1.py
C:\Users\hi\PycharmProjects\Practice2\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py:47: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hi/PycharmProjects/Practice2/P1.py", line 32, in 
    simple_vectorizer = countVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab)
NameError: name 'countVectorizer' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: You must provide a [mcve] if you are requesting debugging help. Please do not post links to code. Post code as formatted text in the question itself.

Comment: Probably because you didn't import it? Presumably something along the lines of [`from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer as countVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#common-vectorizer-usage)

Comment: I thought of that too. When I ran the code only upto that line I am getting a warning as follow: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: You may also want to edit `vocab = ['awesome''terrible']` as without a comma between the strings it just makes a single word `awesometerrible`.

Comment: Added comma. Thanks for that. Still the same error: simple_vectorizer = countVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab)
NameError: name 'countVectorizer' is not defined

Comment: please [edit] your question to include all the code, including any `include`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing **CountVectorizer** but referencing **countVectorizer**.